# How to show rsync speedup

Tags: rsync

Rsync used to show an overall speedup score when the command was completed. There is even reference to the speedup value on the manpage in the --dry-run option, but it seems to have otherwise disappeared.

Not only did I get some personal satisfaction when my speedup value went above 1, it also helped me figure out when it made sense to use rsync.

How do I get speedup back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using? The option `-v` displays the speedup.

This is version 3.1.3

```
$ rsync -av file host:/tmp
sending incremental file list

sent 57 bytes  received 12 bytes  46.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.17
```

Comment: -v was the answer. I am on 3.1.2 - I think I lost speedup a decade ago. Should be added to the man page!